# Is 3m injector cleaner a good product?

Tags: nissan, cleaning, fuel-injection

I want to add an injector cleaner to a Nissan Tiida 2012. It has around 15000 miles and I never add any fuel additive. Sonax injector cleaner costs 20 dollars and 3M costs 10 dollars. Which one do you recommend me? Can you recommend other brands?

Comment: Why do you think you need to add either?  Do you have a problem with the injectors?

Comment: At low RPM the engine sometimes is lugging. I think the word in english is lugging. Also I will do it for general maintance. Also I will check battery fluid, I clean throtle, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3M has always made quality products. I don't know the Sonax brand, so in the interest of fairness I'm going to assume it's very good. But if the 3M product is cheaper, I would gladly spend my own money on it.